# Excel XP for inventory management Simple in theory but can't achieve it

Tags: excel, ms-office, stock, inventory

I need to create a simple and easy to use inventory management sheet or database.

It may be better to use access as I see it, but people is more familiar using excel.

Imagine a warehouse where we store goods. Goods are often delivered so I  have to reduce the stock cound for a particular item. Then if the warehouse is short in some goods, more of these are bought.

The thing is I need to store a history of delivers we make but also store per item the actual count.

I thought having a column for initial items count, then add ins and subtract outs.

I tried using db functions, dynamic tables etc, but the problem is that when I add new registries for new item outs and ins, the dynamic table wont resize it's source and the same for range for functions.

What would be the best way to achieve what I want?
The thing is that we do everything manually, counting, summing and subtracting each time we have ins and outs.
I didn't want to make something overcomplicated to use, but rather save time by automatinc the ins and outs calculations and making it easier to search for particular registries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an Excel Table and a pivot table (or some formulas). The columns should include date, item code, transaction type (coming in or going out), number of units. You can add columns with more information.

Next, enter a starting stock for each item code. Then enter new lines for each transaction. If you have bought new stock, put a positive number into Units. If you have sold or delivered stock, put a negative number.

Then you can build a pivot table that calculates the totals per item code (or use formulas). You can build other pivot tables to calculate values per month or using other data you may want to include in the data entry table.

An Excel Table will automatically adjust formulas and formatting to new rows. If you base the pivot table on the Excel Table, you only need to refresh the pivot table after you have entered new data. If you prefer formulas, you can use Sumifs(), but you need to keep the list of items for the stock totals list up to date manually.

[image]

Comment: Pivot tables seem the way to do it. One question: Is it possible to register ins and outs in separate sheets and use pivot tables in conjunction to do starting+ins-outs?

Comment: Out of the box, pivot tables don't fare well with data spread over several sheets, but with Power Query you can combine different tables into one data table that the pivot tables can look at.